# Apache Flink Iteration on multiple DataSets

Tags: java, redis, distributed, apache-flink

I'm having trouble on implementing a flink batch processing job for my master thesis and would be glad if you could help me.

The requirement:
While having a DataSet of Doubles continuously shrinking in an iteration there are two integer values, that can change over runtime. As far as I know, flink doesn't provide iterations for multiple datasets, only for one. So this is a problem to solve.

My solutions:

1. Having a `DataSet<Tuple3<Double, Integer, Integer>>` which holds the Double value itself and the two integer values for each Double value.
2. Having a distributed key value store for the two integers, which is read and wrote in Rich function's open() and close() method.

Problems:

1. This requires a big amount of RAM, because for each Double value I have to store two additional Integer values. Also, this is not a nice solution, because I actually need only one of them not a single value for each double.
2. There is the big problem: I'm experiencing race conditions, because I don't know how to use "barrier synchronization", means, that I want to update the values only when all the steps for this iteration (and all threads) have finished. But I cannot get it done. Regardless of whether I use the termination criterion for updating or doing it somewhere else, I'm still experiencing race conditions.

Maybe, some of you experienced the same problem or have a solution for me. Thank you in advance! If you wanna see some code, just let me know!

Kind regards from Leipzig, Germany!

Comment: I may not fully understand the requirements of what you have to do, but would flink's .join (or OuterJoin or CoGroup) functionality to combine the datasets give you what you want?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. My first solution states exactly that. My solution was to combine the DataSets but that multiplies the resources I need nearly by the amount of input data, which isn't what I want. I have one Collection of data and two single integers. When I join them, I will need RAM 3x so much as with just the collection and the two integers. You understand? And to get along with that problem, I've had the idea of a distributed cash, which holds the two other values and is written in superstep, but that superstep doesn't seem to exist, because it's called multiple times per iter

Comment: Ok, I follow. That is strange that it increases the used RAM by so much. If it were just doubling the amount of used RAM that would at least suggest that it just is storing a copy of the data (sourceA is 1mb and sourceB is 1mb, added together to get combinedSourceC that is 3mb), which would make some sense (although still not ideal). 

Is it possible for you to try setting up the code to process the data in DataStreams and do the join with those? My reasoning is that because DataStreams and DataSets are handled differently, you won't have the data being duplicated.

Comment: The data will come through each DataStream source (you can take data from a data set and convert it to be sent through as a DataStream) and be combined into a singular object and passed along down the flow of the program. And if you have to be sure that all the data is combined before it continuing down the program, you could set up a session window (not sure if you are familiar with them, but basically you would have one that says "don't execute on the data in this window until you go X amount of time without receiving a new event").